# Determine hostname of Windows system on network

Tags: windows, rdp, hostname

I need to determine the hostname of a remote Windows system. 
Typical DNS-based methods don't work in my situation.

```
ping -a 1.1.1.1
nslookup 1.1.1.1
nbtstat -a -n 1.1.1.1
```

Ideally, to determine what the machine claims it's own hostname is (vs what it has reported at some point), I would like to query the system directly.

Since the RDP service is available on the remote PCs, is there a way to query the RDP service for it's hostname?

(Since I don't know whose computer it is, this request will need be non-intrusive to the end user...)

Comment: Did you look at your DHCP server to see what name the client registered in DHCP?

Comment: Zoredache, the scope I am looking at uses static IPs.

Comment: Which versions of Windows?

Comment: @MarkHenderson This is for Windows 7 and above.

Answer (score 5):

If your client is Windows 7 or newer, you can get this info by WMI as [JimB mentions](https://serverfault.com/a/682723/7709) with a one-liner Powershell:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem -ComputerName 192.168.161.5 | Select-Object Name
```

should work with clients that are Windows Server 2003 or newer.

If you want it as a string instead of an object,

```
Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem -ComputerName 192.168.161.108 | %{$_.Name}
```

Comment: both of these should return system.string objects.  what types are you getting?

Comment: @JimB the last one returns literally just the name, the other one returns `NAME ------ [name]` (pretend there's line breaks in there). I probably phrased it poorly.

Comment: Additionally, the item on the pipeline does differ between the two. The first is `Selected.System.Management.ManagementObject` where `name` is a property, and the second is just `System.String` (shown by `Get-Member`)

Comment: What OS?  I'm getting system.string objects in both cases?  select should be adding a new noteproperty of type system.string with the name of "name" in the first case (because select has to add the property ), and since for each you are choosing to emit only the name property you only get the system.string.  The reason you get the default table is because of the formatting definition of a select object, but both properties are strings (with select if you don't want the object you'd need some more parenthesis)

Answer (score 4):

I would connect to the remote machine via wmi and use win32_computer system.name.  EG (gwmi win32_computersystem -computer 192.168.1.1).name

Comment: Do you have details on how to do this?

Comment: do you want it in vbs or powershell?  for powershell see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176860.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer something more GUIsh, there's an excellent utility named [NetScan](https://www.softperfect.com/products/networkscanner/) (and, IMHO, with better features than other similar utilities).

The great advantage of this utility is that it can add columns with WMI queries results.
It comes with some pre-built WMI queries, but you can add as many as you like.
The query you need is a simple one - SELECT CSName FROM Win32_OperatingSystem

Comment: Upvote for this because this app is amazing. It took almost 5x longer than Angry IP scanner, but it has quite a bit more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Try an IP scanner utility like Angry IP Scanner and see if it can interrogate the server for its host name. I know in Angry there is a column for host name and I often (but not always) see it populate.

Comment: Angry got me most of the way with the hostnames, but it missed about half. This is what initially got me on this thought, but I want to avoid having to do an Angry scan if I am only interrogating one machine..